# JQuery - make colored bar expand up for active link/hover with animation

Tags: jquery, hover

So i've been having some troubles getting this effect to work.  Here is an image of what I am attempting.  It seems like it would be pretty simple, but not sure exactly what to be searching for.

The active link is the Red one in the image, and when you would hover over the other links, I would like it to expand up.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JitP.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vChNU/

So I've created a quick example of the effect (from my understanding) that you're trying to achieve.

The code should be self explanatory, but if you need more of an explanation, please ask.

Can also be achieved with percentages, which saves the problem of figuring out the height of the parent `li`. http://jsfiddle.net/vChNU/1/

Also, your question suggests you'd also like an active state: http://jsfiddle.net/vChNU/2/

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted.  Thanks, nice and simple.  Appreciate it!

Comment: So I was trying to test this in chrome, and copied all the code you used and it doesn't hover when moused over.  Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Hmm that's strange, because I wrote/tested it on chrome (win7) - which version of chrome are you using? Are there any javascript errors? maybe jQuery hadn't been initialised yet?

Comment: I'm using the latest beta on OSX for chrome, but I also tested in Firefox and Safari and still doesn't move.  I'm sure i'm doing something wrong.  I have no javascript errors.  I used the document ready, wouldn't that be correct?  I uploaded it so you could see exactly what I did.  http://devisefunction.org/test/  ....really appreciate the help!

Comment: it seems you've copied over an extra character from jsfiddle - `â€‹`. Try removing that from your custom.js (it's right after the hover method ends)

Comment: Thanks, that character wasn't showing in up dreamweaver which is weird, and didn't notice it until I looked at the source after you said it online.  It works!  Thanks again.